# How to install php 5.5.12 on lubuntu while installing lampstack?

Tags: server, lubuntu, apache2, php, lamp

I have installed apache and mysql according to [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial, but I need to install php 5.5.15 
the `$ sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql` installs php 7.* .

How to do that?

Comment: Search for php and its modules [version 5.5.15] with `apt search name_to_search_for` tto see if its still supported else you will have to build it with support for the various modules you need.

Comment: @George I search there is only php7.* versions. How to built it? I am new to linux

Comment: let whip something up.

Comment: You said lubuntu as a tag, and ubuntu as a title, I'll go with the tag.

Answer (score 1):

To build php5.5.13

1. Download the source file [here](https://secure.php.net/get/php-5.6.13.tar.gz/from/a/mirror) or any other early version [here](https://secure.php.net/releases/)
2. Extract the tarball:

   ```
   tar -xzvf php.tar.gz
   ```
3. Change into the directory:

   ```
   cd php-5.5.13
   ```
4. Install depencies:

   ```
   sudo apt install build-dep php5
   ```
5. Configure php and add to `/usr/local/php5513`:

   ```
   ./configure --disable-debug --disable-rpath --enable-bcmath --enable-calendar -- enable-exif --enable-ftp --enable-fpm --enable-gd-native-ttf --enable-intl --enable-mbregex --enable-mbstring --enable-opcache --enable-pcntl --enable-pdo --enable-shmop --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-sysvmsg --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-wddx --enable-xmlreader --enable-xmlwriter --enable-zip -- prefix=/usr/local/php5513 --with-bz2 --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php5513/etc --with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php5513/php.d --with-curl --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/php5513 --with-gd --with-gettext --with-gmp --with-iconv --with-imap --with-imap-ssl --with-xpm-dir=/usr/local/php5513 --with-vpx-dir=/usr/local/php5513 --with-kerberos --with-libdir=lib64 --with-libxml-dir=/usr/local/php5513 --with-mcrypt --with-openssl --with-pcre-regex --with-pdo-mysql --with-pic --with-png-dir=/usr/local/php5513 --with-snmp --with-xmlrpc --with-xsl --with-zlib --without-gdbm --with-mysqli
   ```
6. Test it:

   ```
   make; make test

   # Any errors please correct them
   ```
7. Install with:

   ```
   make install
   ```
8. Copy sample `php.ini` file and change as desired:

   ```
   cp php.ini-production /usr/local/php5513/etc/php.ini
   ```

**Note:**

1. To use other php configuration files do `mkdir /usr/local/php5513/php.d/` and add them there.
2. To configure php to your taste and needs take note of `step 5`. Remove and add as you desire.

Source:

http://aarvik.dk/how-to-install-php-5-5-15-from-source-and-use-it-with-plesk/

https://www.brandonsavage.net/compiling-php-5-5-from-scratch/

Answer (score 0):

To [install Apache, PHP and MySQL](https://manishpaneri.blogspot.in/2017/01/install-php-on-ubuntu-1604.html), run:

```
sudo apt-get install php7 libapache2-mod-php7 php7-mcrypt
```

Or:

```
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt
```

Or:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
```